# How update tinkter button after finished subprocess and thread yet keeping output pipe to textbox

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, popen

I have a GUI that starts a script when Start button is pressed, using Popen and then starts a thread to pipe the output from that process to a window within the GUI.  The Start button turns yellow and the text changes while the process is running.

Everything works fine, except I would really like the "Start" button to return to it's initial state once the process has finished (green in color, text as "Start").

Everything I've tried, using process.wait or thread.join, interrupts the text updating within the GUI text box.  Any suggestions how to do this while keeping everything else working as it currently does?

My subprocess code, saved to testsubprocess.py is:

```
import time

for i in range(3):
    print("%d.%d" % divmod(i, 10))
    time.sleep(1)
```

My GUI code is:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk # Python 3
from queue import Queue, Empty # Python 3


def iter_except(function, exception):
    """Works like builtin 2-argument `iter()`, but stops on `exception`."""
    try:
        while True:
            yield function()
    except exception:
        return


class DisplaySubprocessOutputDemo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        width=600
        height=350
        xloc=0
        yloc=10
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, xloc, yloc))
        self.root.title('ICR IRN Test')

        
        self.statustext = tk.Text(self.root, height=4, width=30)
        self.statustext.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.startbutton = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Start', command=self.startprocess, bg='green', activebackground = 'orange')
        self.startbutton.config(height = 2, width = 15)
        self.startbutton.grid(row = 5, column=0,sticky='E')
        self.startbuttonpresses = 0
        
        
        exitbutton = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Exit', command=self.quit, bg='red')
        exitbutton.config(height = 2, width = 15)
        exitbutton.grid(row = 5, column=4, sticky='E')
        
        
    def startprocess(self):    
        self.startbuttonpresses = self.startbuttonpresses+1
        
        if self.startbuttonpresses == 1:
            
            self.startbutton.configure(bg='yellow')
            self.startbutton.configure(text='Stop')
         
            self.process = Popen([sys.executable, "-u", "testsubprocess.py"], stdout=PIPE)
    
            # launch thread to read the subprocess output
            #   (put the subprocess output into the queue in a background thread,
            #    get output from the queue in the GUI thread.
            #    Output chain: process.readline -> queue -> label)
            q = Queue(maxsize=1024)  # limit output buffering (may stall subprocess)
            t = Thread(target=self.reader_thread, args=[q])
            t.daemon = True # close pipe if GUI process exits
            t.start()
    
            # show subprocess' stdout in GUI
            self.updatetext(q) # start update loop
            
        
        else:
            self.startbuttonpresses = 0
            self.process.kill()
            self.startbutton.configure(bg='green')
            self.startbutton.configure(text='Start')
            

    def reader_thread(self, q):
        """Read subprocess output and put it into the queue."""
        try:
            with self.process.stdout as pipe:
                for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
                    q.put(line)
        finally:
            q.put(None)


    def updatetext(self, q):
        """Update GUI with items from the queue."""
        for line in iter_except(q.get_nowait, Empty): # display all content
            if line is None:
                return
            else:
                self.statustext.insert(tk.END, line)

        self.root.after(400, self.updatetext, q) # schedule next update


    def quit(self):
        try:
            self.process.kill() # exit subprocess if GUI is closed (zombie!)
        except Exception:
            pass
        self.root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
app = DisplaySubprocessOutputDemo(root)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.quit)
# center window
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've tried to reduce the code a bit - but I think all that remains is the minimum required to show the full functionality - starting the process and redirecting the output from the process to the text box in the GUI.  I have tried watching for when the process has finished, but that interrupts the updating of the text within the text box (nothing is updated until the process is finished and then it all appears as once, whereas I need continuous updating as the process runs).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reset the button after receiving `None` message:

```py
    def updatetext(self, q):
        """Update GUI with items from the queue."""
        for line in iter_except(q.get_nowait, Empty): # display all content
            if line is None:
                # process is finished
                self.startprocess() # reset the button to "Start"
                return
            else:
                self.statustext.insert(tk.END, line)

        self.root.after(400, self.updatetext, q) # schedule next update
```